# NestJS TypeORM InjectRepository Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

Trying to unit test.
Got following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>
> export class UserService {
>
> constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private readonly userRepository:
>   Repository < User>) { }

**spec.ts:**

```
describe('AuthController', () => {
let authController: AuthController;
let authService: AuthService;
let mockRepository = {

};
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
            TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
        ],
        controllers: [AuthController],
        providers: [AuthService, {
            provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
            useValue: mockRepository
        }]
    }).compile()
    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    authController = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController)
});
```

Can someone share a solution please?

**MORE INFO**:

So seems like its something wrong with `typeorm`

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({

    }).compile()
    authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
    authController = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController)
});
```

With this code I'm getting exact the same error. So only problem is adding `typeorm` to this test Module.

So it fails because of dependency: **AuthController->AuthService->UserService->TypeORM**

Btw just checked `UserService` using API with Postman and it works fine.

**Still no result:**

```
 module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        controllers: [AuthController],
        components: [
            {
                provide: AuthService,
                useValue: {}
            },
            {
                provide: UserService,
                useValue: {}
            },
            {
                provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
                useValue: {}
            }
        ],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: AuthService,
                useValue: {}
            },
            {
                provide: UserService,
                useValue: {}
            },
            {
                provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
                useValue: {}
            }
        ]
    }).compile()
    this.authController = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController)
```

Also

```
class AuthServiceMock {
    logIn(userName) {
        return { id:100, isDeleted:false, login:"login", password:"password"};
    }

    signUp() {
        return { expireIn: 3600, token:"token" };
    }
}

describe('AuthController', () => {
let module: TestingModule;
let authController: AuthController;
let authService: AuthService;

beforeEach(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        controllers: [AuthController],
        components: [

        ],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: AuthService,
                useClass: AuthServiceMock
            },
        ]
    }).compile()
    this.authController = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController)
});
```

Comment: Did you solve it somehow? I"m having the same issue

Comment: @alex88 yes. I recreated project and copied all old files to new. Seems like it was some typeorm bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the project you provided in a comment under Kim Kern (https://github.com/rankery/wof-server)

You are using a barrel file (`src/user/index.ts`), exporting the `UserModule`

```js
export * from './user.module';
```

I guess you are using this barrel file to import the module later on.

Now, every time the content of the barrel file is imported , the code contained in the built version of your `src/user/user.module.ts` is executed, which include the decoration of the `UserModule` class, which in turns will make Typeorm try to build a Repository, which causes the error.

You should remove this export from `src/user/index.ts` (or simply delete the file) and fix the broken imports caused by this removal and it should work.

Comment: In order to let more user benefit form your answer, could you provide more explanation please.

Comment: You saved me alive!

Answer (score 2):

I just passed the User entity to Repository and it works.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>
    ) { }

}
```

Checkout docs from here: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database. They have pretty good docs.

Answer (score 2):

I 've spent hours to figure it out and it works

```
 async findAll() {
    
    return await this.userRepository.createCursor(this.userRepository.find()).toArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import `TypeOrmModule.forFeature(...)` you also have to import `TypeOrmModule.forRoot(...)`. But in a unit test, you probably don't want to work with your database but instead mock out all dependencies.

Your controller should not access the database directly, that's what the service is for. So if you want to test your controller and it only injects the service, you should only declare an `AuthService` mock and not import anything:

```
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [{
        provide: AuthService,
        useValue: authServiceMock
    }]
}).compile()
```

If you want to test your `AuthService` and it only injects the repository declare your mockRepository and leave everything else out.

Comment: UserService injects repository and AuthService injects UserService. I tryed ur code but still getting same error.

Comment: Weird, `typeorm` is not involved at all in the controller test. What's the stacktrace of the error, where does it point to?

Comment: Have a look at this test for reference: https://github.com/kiwikern/shassi-nest/blob/master/src/auth/auth.controller.spec.ts

Comment: Its point to @InjectRepository(User) at  at Object.getRepositoryToken

Comment: That's really weird. The actual `UserService` should *never* be instantiated when you unit test the `AuthController` or the `AuthService` with mocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189543/discussion-between-rankery-and-kim-kern).