# TypeORM and MongoDB and Repositories: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, repository, typeorm

I'm trying implement TypeORM with MongoDB using repositories. However, when I try to make use of repositories to manage the database, using the same structure as in [this repository](https://github.com/Jayvirrathi/node-typeorm-mongodb-rest-api/blob/a47c78c6329effece3d46f1f8be6f7320a690b95/src/controllers/user.controller.ts),  things go a bit sideways. I'm getting the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

I have tried the following code:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { getMongoRepository } from "typeorm";
import Task from "../models/Task";

export default class TasksController {
async listAll(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const tasksRepository = getMongoRepository(Task);
    try {
      const tasks = await tasksRepository.find();
      return response.status(200).json({ "items": tasks });
    } catch (err) {
      return response.status(400).json({
        message: err.message,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I know the error refers to implementing the `.find()` method. I have even managed to fetch the data, using a suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009830/nestjs-typeorm-injectrepository-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined) replacing:

```js
const tasks = await tasksRepository.find();
```

with

```js
const tasks = await tasksRepository.createCursor(tasksRepository.find()).toArray();
```

but I still get the above mentioned error.

**Anyone understands what's going on?**

I have also managed to save data directly to the database through the use of the following script:

**server.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm'

const app = express();
const port = 3333;
createConnection();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/tasks', (async (request, response) => {
  const { item } = request.body;
  task.item = item;

  const task = new Task();
  (await connection).mongoManager.save(task);

  return response.send(task);
}))

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
);
```

Answer (score 16):

TypeORM is not support mongodb v4.
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7798

You can use 3.7.0 instead.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Tracking: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8146

Comment: That means things like $lookup would not be possible, Am not such just asking?
What to know if am to downgrade or just switch over to mongoose at once.

Comment: Yea it's really not a viable solution to downgrade MongoDB to use TypeORM. Mongoose is mongoose gets the job done, but obviously lacking some of the TS native finesses TypeORM delivers.. Basically TypeORM needs to be updated to support 4.2

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a pull requests to resolve this. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/8412 if anyone is looking for a workaround in the meantime.